# Implementing a language in Haskell: homogenous lists

Tags: list, haskell, interpreter

I'm trying to create an interpreter for a functional language in haskell (I'm new to the language). I'm creating what's probably a weird mix of minimalism and convenience - no abstract data types, but I want to provide the ability to make homogeneous lists.

So my basic variables  are `data Datum = DatInt Int | DatDbl Double | DatBool Bool` and I've realized I'm not at all sure how to represent homogeneous lists. Adding a constructor `List Datum` or something of the sort would make a heterogeneous list, and making a separate list for each type, i.e. `ListInt [Int] | ListDbl [Double]` would preclude lists of lists.

What would be the best way to go about representing a homogeneous list?

Comment: You can use `List [Datum]` for homogeneous lists, even if it could in principle hold heterogeneous ones as well. If you instead want to _statically_ guarantee that such list is homogeneous, you'll probably need GADTs and possibly existential types. If you are new to Haskell, perhaps it's better to finish your interpreter in the simpler no-static-guarantees way, first. If you feel adventurous, then you can try moving to fancier types.

Comment: Indeed, your current framework doesn't give you any opportunities to encode any type guarantees. If you add a `Function` constructor, you won't be able to make sure functions are applied to the right types either.

Comment: @chi I do want to provide static type guarantees, ideally without having to resort to language extensions. Is it possible at all?

Comment: @dfeuer - why do you say that? So far, without lists, I have a system to provide static type guarantees. I can statically determine the possible return types of a function and the types each argument could be.

Comment: @drowdemon, I don't understand. If you have a function `Int -> Bool` and you have a `Datum` you want to apply it to, you will blow up if the `Datum` isn't a `DatInt`.

Comment: If you want to avoid language extensions, you can look into "final encodings", which Oleg Kiselyov has [written about extensively](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/course/). I'll warn you that they tend to be a bit mind-bending.

Comment: @dfeuer But I can determine whether the `Datum` is a `DatInt` statically at compile time, rather than having to run code, determine the type of the argument, and then error.

Comment: Ah, so these are the types of *expressions* in your language, which you wish to *typecheck* and then *compile*? That is reasonable. But in that case, you should surely follow @chi's advice and allow this datatype to represent ill-typed code, and (optionally) create a different, fancy, datatype to represent type-checked code.

Comment: If you want to avoid a fancy datatype, you can still mark things up, annotating the expression tree with type tags. So you'd have something like `List Tag [Datum]`, which holds the `Datum` values along with a tag indicating what type each of them is *supposed* to have.

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks! Tagging them like that is probably what I'll do. I'd accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One useful notion (whether you're going for sexy types or not) is that of a type tag. The non-sexy version is a lot easier to deal with.

```
data Tag = IntTag
         | DoubleTag
         | BoolTag
         | ListTag Tag
   deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Now your types are represented by these various tags. An `Int` is represented by `IntTag`. A list of `Int` is represented by `ListTag IntTag`.

Now you can represent type-annotated expressions something like this:

```
data Expr = IntLit Int
          | DoubleLit Double
          | BoolLit Bool
          | ListLit Tag [Expr]

-- Check that an expression is validly annotated
typeCheck :: Expr -> Maybe Tag
typeCheck IntLit{} = Just IntTag
...
typeCheck (ListLit tag els)
  | all good els = Just (ListTag tag)
  | otherwise = Nothing
  where
    good el = case typeCheck el of
                Nothing -> False
                Just res = res == tag
```

Comment: To make this properly extensible, I think there needs to be two functions `checkType :: Type -> Expr -> Maybe ()` and `inferType :: Expr -> Maybe Type`, so that `inferType (ListLit tag els) = mapM_ (checkType tag) els >> return (ListTag tag)` and `checkType (ListTag t) (ListLit t' els) = guard (t == t') >> mapM_ (checkType t) els; checkType _ ListLit{} = Nothing`